# Unable to delete a node from Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete `Room2` node from the Firebase database. I have this database structure:

```
db-24f7f
 |
 - Hotel
       |
    -Room1
         |
          beds:"2"
          Chairs: "6"
    -Room2
         |
         beds:"3"
         Chairs: "8"
```

I tried as

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference();
database.getReference("Hotel").orderByChild("Chairs").equalTo("8").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
    }
```

That delete the whole database. Then I tried as

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference();
database.getReference("Hotel").orderByChild("Chairs").equalTo("8").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ds.getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }
```

and find this :

> 12-28 12:31:21.813 22950-22950/PKGName_o E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>   12-28 12:31:21.813 22950-22950/PKGName_o  E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>   W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "Chairs"' at Hotel to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

After this, the node does not delete from the Firebase. Why it is unable to delete the node?

Comment: Your second code is fine, it should work already. And the logcat only shows a warning, the firebase sdk suggests you to add that index option to the Firebase Database Rules. Your code will work if you don't add that rule.
I have tried your code using the same database and the Room2 removed as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Room node add the room key.

```
db-24f7f
 |
 - Hotel
       |
    -Room1
         |
          beds:"2"
          roomKey: "Room1"
          Chairs: "6"
    -Room2
         |
         beds:"3"
         roomKey: "Room2"
         Chairs: "8"
```

Now take the reference of the 'Hotel'.

```
DatabaseReference hotelRef = myRef.child("Hotel");
```

If you just want to remove Room2, then do so by setting the value of Room2 to `null`-

```
hotelRef.child("Room2").setValue(null);
```

If you want to delete all the rooms with 8 chairs, then -

```
hotelRef.orderByChild("Chairs").equalTo("8").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String roomKey = (String) ds.child(roomKey).getValue();
                        hotelRef.child(roomKey).setValue(null);
                    }
                }
```